# What do you mean by Ciphertext indistinguishability

Tags: encryption, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack, ciphertext-only-attack

Wiki definition :

> A cryptosystem is considered secure in terms of indistinguishability
>   if no adversary, given an encryption of a message randomly chosen from
>   a two-element message space determined by the adversary, can identify
>   the message choice with probability significantly better than that of
>   random guessing (1⁄2). If any adversary can succeed in distinguishing
>   the chosen ciphertext with a probability significantly greater than
>   1⁄2, then this adversary is considered to have an "advantage" in
>   distinguishing the ciphertext, and the scheme is not considered secure
>   in terms of indistinguishability. This definition encompasses the
>   notion that in a secure scheme, the adversary should learn no
>   information from seeing a ciphertext. Therefore, the adversary should
>   be able to do no better than if it guessed randomly.

I understood the meaning of this but what do you mean by `Indistinguishability under chosen-plaintext attack` and `Indistinguishability under chosen ciphertext attack` ? Could anyone give me an example, and answer in easy understanding language.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/991 ​ ​

Comment: I think with a good definition of the two terms - as provided by the link of Ricky Demer - we could close this as a dupe, but keep it as bait for search engines in case somebody searches for same? Or do you need more explained, python?