# For the symmetric-key encryption algorithm, is it possible to use the exponent and modulo to be the keys

Tags: algorithm-design

**For example:**

Encrypt with: $M^{k_1} \bmod k_2$

where $M$ is message, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are independent keys

If it is possible, what is the decryption algorithm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'mod' can be reversed, so it is not possible.
Consider k1 = 2, k2 = 6.
Now,
M = 1 => C (ciphertext) = 1.
M = 5 => C = 1

You have no way of knowing whether the cleartext was 1 or 5, as you get the same ciphertext for both.

Answer (score 1):

So it's $$C=M^{k_1}\bmod{k_2}$$for decryption you need $k_1 \text{ and } k_2$ and $\gcd(\varphi(k_2),k_1)=1$ must hold where $\varphi:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ is the [euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient).

The formula is $M=C^{k_1^{-1}\bmod{\varphi(k_2)}}\bmod{k_2}$.

So why does this work?

We're constructing a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) here, $\mathbb Z_{k_2}^*$ by applying all operations $\bmod{k_2}$. This ring has [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $\varphi(k_2)$ and thus we can do the same as we would with [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and find the inverse of the encryption exponent in the ring of the order ($\mathbb Z_{\varphi(k_2)}^*$) by finding $d$ such that $k_1\cdot d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(k_2)}$ which is normally written as $d=k_1^{-1}\bmod{\varphi(k_2)}$.

---

Please note: Analyzing the basic security of this scheme is non-trivial, because of the relations $M,k_1,k_2$ may have with each other (f.ex. $m$ could only generate a small subgroup, [the factorization of $\varphi(k_2)$ may be smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm), ...) and of course this scheme is *not* [IND-CPA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26738/23623) secure as it stands (because it is deterministic).