# How to determine the correct padding to use for rsa signing?

Tags: rsa, signature, rsa-pss

Before today I didn't know the difference between RSA padding for encryption and for signing, I think [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43866/padding-on-rsa-signature-and-rsa-encryption) describes it pretty succinctly, however, I don't know if there is an optimal padding to use or if there are any deficiencies in current paddings I should be wary of (for example, [PKCS for RSA encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32050/what-specific-padding-weakness-does-oaep-address-in-rsa)).

I came across RSA-FDH and RSASSA-PSS, but don't know if there are any other paddings available for RSA signing or if the ones I mentioned have any known weaknesses/deficiencies.

Comment: Both RSA-FDH and RSASSA-PSS have security proofs. They mostly differ in details (can you construct large-output hashes? do you mind deterministic signatures? Do you need a widely supported scheme?)