# What do the signature security abbreviations like EUF-CMA mean?

Tags: provable-security, terminology, chosen-plaintext-attack, known-plaintext-attack, security-definition

From time to time, one stumbles across formal security definitions. This includes security definitions for signature schemes.

The most common ones are the **`*UF-*`** ones, advertising security against specific classes of attackers.
Now these notions may not be that well-understood by many people so I ask hereby for a canonical answer, that explains what the following security notions mean. A (simple) description of the formal attack scenario is preferred.

Please don't restrict the answer to "you can chose this and if you can break it with this it isn't EUF-CMA". Please at least outline the formal attack (like f.ex. generate a new signature).

The following list is in order of strength for the same suffix (x)or prefix:

- UUF-KMA
- SUF-KMA
- EUF-KMA
- UUF-CMA
- SUF-CMA
- EUF-CMA

Comment: The purpose of this question is the same as the of [the "IND-" question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/23623).

Comment: German wikipedia has started collecting this: [Sicherheitseigenschaften kryptografischer Verfahren](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherheitseigenschaften_kryptografischer_Verfahren).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

| Notation. |
| --- |

Sets are represented using the calligraphic font and algorithms using the straight font. Throughout, $\Sigma:=(\mathsf{K},\mathsf{S},\mathsf{V})$ denotes a signature scheme on a key-space $\mathcal{K}$, message-space $\mathcal{M}$ and signature-space $\mathcal{S}$.
Since only a single key-pair is involved in the discussion, to avoid cluttering, let's drop the security parameter, public key and secret key when invoking $\mathsf{S}$; similarly, let's drop the security parameter and public key while invoking $\mathsf{V}$. That is, we regard:
$\mathsf{S}:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{S}$ and
$\mathsf{V}:\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$.

| Security modelling |
| --- |

As in the case of encryption schemes, security is modelled for a signature scheme $\Sigma$ using a game between a challenger and an adversary $\mathsf{A}$ (a polynomial-time probabilistic machine). The game models a possible scenario where $\mathsf{A}$ tries to *break* $\Sigma$ using an *attack* when the challenger is using the scheme $\Sigma$. $\Sigma$ is said to be secure in the  $\mathtt{break}$-$\mathtt{attack}$-model (i.e., $\mathtt{break}$-$\mathtt{attack}$-secure) if it is "difficult for any $\mathsf{A}$'' to $\mathtt{break}$ $\Sigma$ under $\mathtt{attack}$ (the precise definition is given in the end). Hence, for the case of signature schemes $\mathtt{break}\in${UF,SF,EF} and $\mathtt{attack}\in${KOA,CMA,KMA}---it is possible to consider any combination of these.

For ease of exposition, let's start with the description of the "weakest" model, called universal forgery  (UF) under key-only attack (KOA).

| *1: UF-KOA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Universal Forgery (UF) under Key-Only Attack (KOA) |
| --- | --- |

1. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$
2. a. Challenge $\mathsf{A}$ on an arbitrary message $m^*\in\mathcal{M}$

   b. Receive as response (to the challenge) a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$

That is, in the UF-KOA model, the adversary has forged on a message chosen by the challenger (i.e., a universal forgery) given just the public key (i.e., the key-only attack). In this model, the adversary has the hardest-possible task: it is given only the bare minimum required to forge---i.e., the public key---and has no choice on which message to forge on.

In practice, an adversary could have means to obtain more information than this---e.g., it might procure, through some channel, a signature issued by the signer. This is not captured by the UF-KOA model and hence the reason to deem it *weak*. There are two ways to *strengthen* it: *one*, we could make the task of the adversary easier (e.g., let it forge on a message of its own choice); and/or *two*, we could provide it more information (e.g., give it signatures on messages of its choice). Let's now take a look at a model, called UF under *known-message attack* (KMA), that does the latter.

| *2: UF-KMA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Universal Forgery (UF) under *Known-Message Attack* (KMA) |
| --- | --- |

1. a. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$

   b. Sample $q=q(n)$ arbitrary messages $m_1,...,m_q\in\mathcal{M}$, and generate signatures $\sigma_i\leftarrow\mathsf{S}(m_i)$, $1\le i \le q$
2. a. Send the set $\{(m_1,\sigma_1),...,(m_q,\sigma_q)\}$ to $\mathsf{A}(1^n)$, and challenge it on an arbitrary message $m^*\not\in \{m_1,...,m_q\}$

   b. Receive as response from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$

Although $\mathsf{A}$ has to still produce a universal forgery, it now gets---unlike in the UF-KOA model---a bunch of signatures on messages it knows (the known-message attack). The model can be further strengthened by allowing $\mathsf{A}$ to query and obtain signatures on messages of *its* choice. This yields the model, given below, called UF under *chosen-message attack* (CMA).

| *3: UF-CMA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Universal Forgery (UF) under *Chosen-Message Attack* (CMA) |
| --- | --- |

1. a. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$

   b. Initialise a set $\mathcal{M}'=\emptyset$.
2. If $\mathsf{A}$ queries for signature on a message $m\in\mathcal{M}$, responds with $\mathsf{S}(m)$, and add $m$ to $\mathcal{M}'$
3. a. Challenge $\mathsf{A}$ on an arbitrary message $m^*\not\in\mathcal{M}'$

   b. Receive as response from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$

Next, let's look at strengthening the model from the second aspect, i.e., by weakening the notion of what it means for an adversary to *break* the signature scheme. We go from universal forgery, which was discussed in the first experiment, to selective forgery (SF) and finally to existential forgery (EF) in the setting of KOA.

| *4: SF-KOA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Selective Forgery (SF) under Key-Only Attack (KOA) |
| --- | --- |

1. Receive from $\mathcal{A}$ the *commitment* $m^*\in\mathcal{M}$: $\mathsf{A}$ has to forge on $m^*$ in the end
2. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$
3. Receive as response from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$

Note that although $\mathcal{A}$ has to a priori commit to the message it forges on, it still has more freedom than in the UF-KOA game---for EF-KOA, this restriction is also lifted.

| *5: EF-KOA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Existential Forgery (EF) under Key-Only Attack (KOA) |
| --- | --- |

1. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$
2. Receive as response from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$

In a similar vein, it is possible to define the models $\mathtt{break}$-$\mathtt{attack}$ for $\mathtt{break}\in${SF,EF} and $\mathtt{attack}\in${KMA,CMA}. The strongest model of the lot---i.e., EF-CMA---is defined below as it is considered to be the model on which security of signature schemes should be based on.

| *6: EF-CMA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | Existential Forgery (EF) under *Chosen-Message Attack* (CMA) |
| --- | --- |

1. a. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$

   b. Initialise a set $\mathcal{M}'=\emptyset$.
2. If $\mathsf{A}$ queries for signature on a message $m\in\mathcal{M}$, respond with $\mathsf{S}(m)$, and add $m$ to $\mathcal{M}'$
3. Receive as output from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$ and $m^*\not\in\mathcal{M}'$

That is, in the EF-CMA-model, the adversary can obtain a bunch of signatures on messages it chooses adaptively, and, in the end, can forge on any *fresh* message. A stronger version of this definition ---called the *strong* EF-CMA (sEF-CMA)---is also considered desirable.

| *7: sEF-CMA$^{\mathsf{A}}_\Sigma(1^n)$* | strong Existential Forgery (sEF) under *Chosen-Message Attack* (CMA) |
| --- | --- |

1. a. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^n)$ and run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^n,pk)$

   b. Initialise a set $\mathcal{M}'=\emptyset$.
2. If $\mathsf{A}$ queries for signature on a message $m\in\mathcal{M}$, respond with $\sigma=\mathsf{S}(m)$, and add $(m,\sigma)$ to $\mathcal{M}'$
3. Receive as output from $\mathsf{A}$ a forgery $(m^*,\sigma^*)$: $\mathsf{A}$ wins if $\mathsf{V}(\sigma^*,m^*)=1$ and $(m^*,\sigma^*)\not\in\mathcal{M}'$

That is, the adversary can forge on a message on which it queried for a signature *as long as* the forgery is different from the one it received as a response to the query (i.e. a strong existential forgery).

| P.S. (post scriptum) |
| --- |

1. Definition. A signature scheme is said to be $\mathtt{break}$-$\mathtt{attack}$-secure if for all probabilistic polynomial-time adversaries $\mathsf{A}$
   $$\Pr[\mathsf{A}\ wins\ \mathtt{break}-\mathtt{attack}_\Sigma^{\mathsf{A}}(1^n)]=negl(n).$$
   where $\mathtt{break}\in${UF,SF,EF} and $\mathtt{attack}\in${KOA,CMA,KMA}.
2. Although only signature schemes are discussed, the definitions can be easily adapted for message-authentication codes (MACs). In particular:

   1. As the key generation algorithm generates only the symmetric key $k$, in Step 1 of the security models, there no key to be handed over to $\mathsf{A}$. As a consequence, UF-KOA is difficult in an information-theoretic sense.
   2. Instead of querying for a signature on messages, $\mathsf{A}$ queries for tags.
3. There are other variants of attacks and breaks --- see [GMR], for example.

| References |
| --- |

- [GMR88]: Goldwasser, Micali and Rivest. A digital signature scheme secure against adaptive chosen-message attacks. [(PDF)](https://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Digital%20Signatures/A_Digital_Signature_Scheme_Secure_Against_Adaptive_Chosen-Message_Attack.pdf)
- [BN00] : Mihir Bellare and Chanathip Namprempre. Authenticated Encryption: Relations among notions and analysis of the generic composition paradigm [PDF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2000/025.pdf)

Comment: +1 very good answer. Still, even though the question didn't strictly ask for it and you also mentioned that other variants exist, I think it would be good if you could also add in an explicit description of *strong* EUF-CMA. From my experience, the rather weak UUF/SUF and KOA/KMA notions are seldom used in the literature, whereas strong EUF-CMA is very often needed (here it is a little unfortunate that the OP already used the term SUF for selective security, since I guess most papers that write SUF actually means *strong* EUF(-CMA)).

Comment: I have seen authors use sEUF to refer to strong existential unforgeability. I will add it to the list.