# Does this pairing-based signature scheme work?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, pairings

Suppose $g$ is a pairing-friendly elliptic curve with subgroup generators $G_1$ and $G_2$. Suppose also that $M$ is the message I want to sign.

**Setup**

1. Compute $A = a \cdot G_1$ and $P = p \cdot G_2$, where $a$ and $p$ are some secret values.
2. The public key is then defined as a tuple $(A, P)$.

**Signature**

1. Hash message $M$ to a number using a hash function: $m=Hash(M)$.
2. Compute  $C = \frac{p}{a \cdot m} \cdot G_2$.
3. The signature is then defined as $C$.

**Verification**

1. Compute $m = Hash(M)$.
2. Verify that $e(A, C)^m = e(G_1, P)$.

Are there any holes in this scheme?

Comment: This scheme falls to the same attack as your last suggestion: You can compute any $C=1/(am)\cdot P$ to forge a message.

Comment: But in this scheme $a$ is not public - so, the attacker shouldn't be able to calculate $am$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Attackers can just choose an $a$ themselves...

Comment: Ah! I've updated the scheme by moving $A$ into the public key. Is it still broken?

Comment: Let $C$ be a signature for $M$. We compute a signature for $M'$ by computing $x=H(M')/H(M)$ and $C' = \frac{1}{x}\cdot C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed signature scheme falls to universal forgeries under a known message attack ([UF-KMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/what-do-the-signature-security-abbreviations-like-euf-cma-mean/44210#44210)).

The adversary $\mathcal{A}$ receives the public key $(A,P)$, a single message signature pair $(M,C)$ and the challenge message $M^*$.
It outputs $$C' := \frac{H(M)}{H(M^*)} \cdot C.$$

The adversary described above is succesful with probability $1$.
To see this, consider that $C$ is by definition
$$C = \frac{p}{a\cdot H(M)} \cdot G_2.$$
We now have 
\begin{align}
C' &= \frac{H(M)}{H(M^*)} \cdot C\\
&= \frac{H(M)}{H(M^*)}\cdot\frac{p}{a\cdot H(M)} \cdot G_2\\
&=\frac{p\cdot H(M)}{a\cdot H(M) H(M^*)} \cdot G_2\\
&=\frac{p}{a\cdot H(M^*)} \cdot G_2,
\end{align}
which is exactly the signature of $M^*$ and will therefore be accepted by the verification equation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work; forgeries are still easy.

Suppose the attacker has a valid signature $C$ for a message $M$ with $e(A, C)^m = e(G_1, P)$

Now, the attacker has a second message $M'$ with $m' = \text{Hash}(M')$.

Then, the attacker computes $C' = (m'^{-1} \cdot m)C$

Then, we have $e(A, C')^{m'} = e(A, m' C') = e(A, mC) = e(A, C)^m$, which agrees with the constant (for a public key) $e(G_1, P)$, and so $C'$ is a valid forgery for $M'$