# Does Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES) provide IND-CCA2 security?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, chosen-ciphertext-attack, ecies

I am looking for a faster alternative to RSA with OAEP as a IND-CCA2 public key scheme. Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme might be a candidate, but I am not sure if it provides IND-CCA2 security.

So the question is if ECIES offers IND-CCA2 security by default? If not, what should be changed so that it does offer it?

Comment: Yes. ECIES is CCA2-secure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Are you aware of a formal proof that I can refer to?

Comment: @YehudaLindell Would you mind expanding on that and putting it in an answer?

Comment: @sejpm’s answer is sufficient. I suggest looking at the paper. Note that Katz Lindell doesn’t give a proof of this, but only explains the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is if ECIES gives by default IND-CCA2 security?

Yes it does. There's a proof in modern Cryptography by Katz and Lindell, but I'll leave that one to Yehuda to write an answer around. This answer will instead be based on [DHIES (PDF)](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/dhies.pdf) which is the generalization of ECIES and essentially does an ephemeral DH key exchange with the public key, hashes the shared secret and performs an encrypt-then-mac authenticated encrytion of the payload using the hashed secret.

The paper states the security bound as

$$\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{ind-cca-fg}}_\text{DHIES}(t,q,\mu,c)
\leq
\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{ind-cpa-fg}}_\text{SYM}(t,0,0)+
2\cdot\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{odh}}_{\mathcal G,H}(t,q)+
2\cdot\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{suf-cma}}_\text{MAC}(t,1,c,q,\mu)$$

with $t$ being the upper bound on the time complexity of the adversary and $q$ being the upper bound on the number of decryption queries and $\mu$ being the upper bound on the number of bits asked to the decryption oracle and $c$ being an upper bound on the length of the challenge ciphertext for the CCA experiment. $\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{suf-cma}}_\text{MAC}$ is the [SUF-CMA security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44210/23623) of the MAC and $\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{ind-cpa-fg}}_\text{SYM}$ is the [CPA security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26738/23623) of the symmetric cipher.

Now only remains $\mathrm{Adv}^{\text{odh}}_{\mathcal G,H}$ which is the advantage with which an adversary can distinguish $(g^u,g^v,H(g^{uv}))$ from $(g^u,g^v,R)$ with $R,u,v$ being randomly sampled from either the group or the hash output set. Additionally the adversary is given access to an oracle computing $\mathcal H_v(X)=H(X^v)$.

So if the above *Oracle Diffie-Hellman* (ODH) assumption is hard for the given group (and it should be for elliptic curves), and if the symmetric cipher and the MAC are secure, then ECIES is also secure.