# What is the difference between Forgery and Chosen-Message Attacks?

Tags: forgery

I did some researches about forgery attack and chosen-message attack.

For me, forgery attacks are more focused on the verifiability whereas chosen-message attacks are similar to brute-force attacks.

I am in the right way? If not, could you help me to understant better.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean mac forgery by forgery attack?

Comment: I would like to know in general the difference between them? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the [forgery of a Digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature_forgery) ( or a MAC), the signature system has a flaw so that the attackers are able to create a message $m$ and a valid signature $\sigma = sign(m)$ that has never been created by the valid user ( the owner of the signature key).

The forgery is the target/aim of the attacker against a digital signature<sup>*</sup>. Like in the encryption schemes, we have game settings between the attacker and challenger.

There are various models for signature security, for details, see our [canonical Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/18298). What you considered is;

- **UF under Chosen-Message Attack (UF-CMA)**.

  The adversary $\mathsf{A}$ is a polynomial-time probabilistic machine, $\mathcal{M}$ is the message space, $\mathsf{K} $ is the keyspace and $\lambda$ is the security parameter. The game;

  1. Sample key $(sk,pk)\leftarrow\mathsf{K}(1^\lambda)$, run the adversary $\mathsf{A}(1^\lambda,pk)$ and initialise a set $\mathcal{M}'=\emptyset$.
  2. If $\mathsf{A}$ queries for signature on a message $m\in\mathcal{M}$, responds with $\sigma(m)$, and add $m$ to $\mathcal{M}'$
  3. a. Challenge $\mathsf{A}$ on an arbitrary message $m^*\not\in\mathcal{M}'$

In this attack, the adversary chooses the messages as they like so that they learn information about the signature system. Then, given the challenge message they produce a valid signature on the signature scheme.

An example attack was executed on  ISO/IEC 9796–1 Signature Scheme by our moderator;

- 2000, [A Chosen Messages Attack on the ISO/IEC 9796–1 Signature Scheme](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070070-new.pdf) FGrieu.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>There is also a total break in which the adversary access the signature key!</sub>

Comment: I've changed the answer, The OP was talking about UF-CMA not CPA (removed from tags).