# RSA Signature using SHA-256 is secure?

Tags: rsa, signature, sha-256

Is following RSA signature scheme secure against forgery and prevents breaking text book RSA?

$$y = \operatorname{SHA-256}(m)$$
$$s = y^d\bmod N$$

where $m$ is message of arbitrary length, $y$ is the 256-bit hash of $m$ computed using SHA-256, $d$ is RSA private key, and $N$ is an RSA modulus with length 2048 or higher?

Comment: There is already [RSA-FDH](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95940/18298) that this answer covers your needs.

Comment: SHA-256 is not wide enough that the security argument of RSA-FDH applies. On the contrary, the [Desmedt and Odlyzko attack applies](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51680/555) to some degree to break EUF-CMA. With how much work, well, that requires care... See [this](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/iso97962joc.pdf#page=4) \[link fixed\]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An obvious way to attack this (and we're shorten $\text{SHA256}(m)$ as $S(m)$ :

- For a large number of messages $m_i$, compute $S(m_i)$, and factor that.  If it is smooth, record the message and the prime factors in a table; if it is not smooth, reject it
- When you have recorded enough messages (and prime factors) in your table, do elimination on the prime factor table to find a set of messages and factors where all the primes of the selected messages, when multiplied by the factors, all sum to 0.

If we have such a product (and the multiplier corresponding to one of the messages, say, $S(m_0)$, is 1), then we have (where $p_i$ is the multiplier we assigned to message $i$):

$$S(m_1)^{-p_1} \cdot S(m_2)^{-p_2} \cdot ... \cdot S(m_n)^{-p_n} \equiv S(m_0)$$

So, ask for the signatures of $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$; from that, you can deduce the signature for $m_0$.

So, how feasible is this?  Well, the bulk of the logic is reminiscent of what is done in the Quadratic Field Sieve (QFS); the size (256 bits) is about what you get when you apply QFS to a 512 bit modulus.  QFS can factor 512 bit modulii feasibly; I conclude that this algorithm would also be feasible.

Comment: @fgrieu: better???

Comment: Yes. But even a mod can't upvote twice!