# Rabin-Williams signature and it's reduction to factorization

Tags: signature, provable-security, rabin-cryptosystem

Rabin signature is rightly [celebrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rabin_signature_algorithm#Security) as a signature scheme with provable reduction to factorization. How do we show that for Rabin-Williams signature as standardized, under the common and realistic hypothesis that the adversary has access to a signature oracle?

---

I'll describe in detail the standardized modular arithmetic in Rabin-Williams signature, per ISO/IEC 9796-2:2010 appendix B, or almost equivalently ISO/IEC 14888-2:2008 RW or IEEE P1363-2000 IFSP-RW/IFVP-RW¹. I assume signature with appendix per [Full Domain Hash](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/fdh.pdf) because I don't want to dive into padding and message recovery, but the reasoning also applies to deterministic paddings in these standards.

Security parameter $k$ is the public modulus size in bits. For the padding, we assume a hash function $H_k:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^{k-5}$ with result assimilated to an integer in $[0,2^{k-5})$, and that this hash is undistinguishable from a Random Oracle.

- Key generation $\mathsf{Gen}$: on input $1^k$

  1. draw random primes $p,q\in[2^{(k-1)/2},2^{k/2}]$ with $p\equiv3\pmod8$ and $q\equiv7\pmod8$, which turns out to be possible $\forall k>10$
  2. compute $n\gets p\,q$, which is exactly $k$-bit
  3. set $e\gets2$ and compute $d\gets e^{-1}\bmod(\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)/2)$
  4. output $\mathrm{Pub}=(n,e)$ and $\mathrm{Priv}=(n,d)$.
- Signature $\mathsf{Sign}$: on input $\mathrm{Priv}=(n,d)$ and message $M$

  1. compute $k\gets\left\lceil\,\log_2(n)\right\rceil$
  2. compute *message representative* $m\gets16\,H_k(M)+12$ [with thus $m\in[0,2^{k-1})$ and $m\equiv12\pmod{16}$ ]
  3. compute² the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) $j\gets\left(\frac m n\right)$
  4. compute $g\gets\begin{cases}m/2&\text{if }\,j=-1\\m&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad$[with thus $\left(\frac g n\right)\ge0$ ]
  5. compute $r\gets g^d\bmod n$
  6. compute and output the signature $s\gets\min(r,n-r)$.
- Verification $\mathsf{Ver}$: on input $\mathrm{Pub}=(n,e)$, message $M$ and signature $s$

  1. set $k\gets\left\lceil\,\log_2(n)\right\rceil$
  2. compute *message representative* $m\gets16\,H_k(M)+12$ [with thus $m\in[0,2^{k-1})$ and $m\equiv12\pmod{16}$ ]
  3. if $s\not\in[0,(n+1)/2)$ then output $\mathtt{Invalid}$ and stop
  4. compute $t\gets s^e\bmod n$ and $u\gets t\bmod8$
  5. if $u\not\in\{1,4,6,7\}$ then output $\mathtt{Invalid}$ and stop
  6. set $v\gets\begin{cases}t&\text{if }\,u=4\\n-t&\text{if }\,u=1\\
     2\,t&\text{if }\,u=6\\2\,(n-t)&\text{if }\,u=7\end{cases}$
  7. if $m\ne v$ then output $\mathtt{Invalid}$ and stop
  8. output $\mathtt{Valid}$.

Soundness can be proved using that for all $x\in\mathbb Z,\,x^2\equiv{\left({\left(x^2\right)}^d\right)}^e\pmod n$.

The values of $u$ allowed at $\mathsf{Ver}_5$ and cases at $\mathsf{Ver}_6$ correspond to $m\equiv12\pmod{16}$ after $\mathsf{Sign}_2$ and $\mathsf{Ver}_2$, per this table (where for large $k$ it's impossible in practice to find $M$ that triggers any of the four right cases):

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrr|rrrr}
\left(\frac m p\right)&+1&-1&-1&+1&+1& 0&-1& 0\\
\left(\frac m q\right)&+1&-1&+1&-1& 0&+1& 0&-1\\
\hline
\left(\frac m n\right)&+1&+1&-1&-1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
u                     & 4& 1& 6& 7& 4& 4& 1& 1
\end{array}$$

Observation: adversaries with access to signatures of known arbitrary messages can compute $u\gets (s^e\bmod n)\bmod 8$, thus deduce $\left(\frac m p\right)$ and $\left(\frac m q\right)$ for known pseudo-random $m\equiv12\pmod{16}$. When without access to these signatures I only see they could get at the lesser information $\left(\frac m n\right)=\left(\frac m p\right)\,\left(\frac m q\right)$.

---

Questions [please ignore 1 and 3, I got them [solved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89750/555)!]

1. <sub><strike>Is there an argument that the above observation can't give an adversary with access to signatures (or a signature oracle) some insight on the factorization of $n$?</strike></sub>
2. How do we prove that this Rabin-Williams signature is [sEF-CMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44210/555) (Strongly secure against Existential Forgery under Chosen-Message Attack), assuming factorization of $n$ as output by $\mathsf{Gen}$ is hard?
3. <sub><strike>Are these reductions to factorization all *towards* the security of the scheme, or do they somewhat go *against* it (leaving out side-channels and other [implementation-specific attacks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/368.pdf))? My concern is that existential break with signature oracle ⟹ factorization ⟹ total break is not intuitively reassuring.</strike></sub>

---

Update: perhaps the answer to 2 is in Bernstein's [*Proving tight security for Rabin-Williams signatures*](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwtight-20080201.pdf), originally in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 2008](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78967-3_5), but I have a hard time following that paper³, or even ascertain the question's scheme is his α-|principal| with B=0 (thus fixed).

---

¹ IEEE P1363-2000 cites ISO/IEC 9796:1991 and Hugh C. Williams' [*A modification of the RSA public-key encryption procedure*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hugh-Williams-6/publication/3083444_A_Modification_of_the_RSA_Public-Key_Encryption_Procedure/links/0a85e52f8eff22ae29000000/A-Modification-of-the-RSA-Public-Key-Encryption-Procedure.pdf#page=2) (in [IEEE TIT, 1980](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1980.1056264)) as it's origin. ISO/IEC 9796:1991 uses $m\equiv6\pmod{16}$ at $\mathsf{Sign}_2$ and $\mathsf{Ver}_2$, which requires minor adjustments at $\mathsf{Ver}_5$ and $\mathsf{Ver}_6$, see the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)'s [*Modified-Rabin signature scheme*](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap11.pdf#page=16) (starting page marked 439 following 11.27).

² One can compute $j\gets\left(\frac m n\right)$ per [algorithm 2.149](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap2.pdf#page=27) in the Handbook of Applied Cryptography. Bernstein gives a method [avoiding Jacobi symbols](https://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf#page=6) by making $p$ and $q$ part of the private key, reusing computations needed when using the Chinese Reminder Theorem to speed-up private-key operation, and other optimizations using precomputed values.

³ And I respectfully disagree on one count: the motivation of the $\min$ step in $\mathsf{Sign}_6$ is stated as:

> the point is that ($s$) takes a bit less space than ($r$)

but that's missing another objective: having sEF-CMA rather than EF-CMA, by allowing the check in $\mathsf{Ver}_3$, which prevent an adversary from changing $s$ into an equally valid signature $n-s$, which would break sEF-CMA.

Comment: Note that I _think_ FDH schemes have a tendency to also require to model the hash as a random oracle which is technically an additional assumption.

Comment: As far as I can tell this _is_ indeed a $B=0$ |principal| signature, or close enough to it. Bernstein leaves a tight reduction (to factorization) of this type of signature as an open question at the end of section 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still piecing things together, so bear with me as this may be revised.

1. Access to a signature oracle is either a zero-knowledge resource or breaks the random oracle model for $H_k$. To see this we observe that anyone can generate valid $(m,s)$ pairs for random values of $H_k$. They do this by picking arbitrary $s$ in the required range, squaring to get a $t$ and either discarding or going through verification step 6 to get a $m$ value. The only thing that they don't know is the $M$ that generated $H_k$, but the random oracle means that this information does not help in factoring $n$.
2. There is no special forgery to produce a separate signature for a given $M$ as the process is deterministic. It suffices therefore to show EUF-CMA. Suppose that an attacker can exhibit a forgery $(M,s)$ then their method must either produce $s$ before $M$ is fully specified or $M$ before $s$ is fully specified. If the former, they could have reconstructed $H_k(M)$ before knowing $M$ (it can't be a repeated message) and so have an improved chance of finding $M$ given $H_k(M)$ which violates our random oracle. If $M$ is fully specified before $s$, then the attacker has a means to construct one of $\sqrt m$, $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt m$, $\sqrt 2\sqrt m$ or $\sqrt{-2}\sqrt m$ (according to the choice in step 6) for a $m=16H_k+12$ with random $H_k$ with improved chances. We choose many random $x$, square them and see if the form matches a $u$ and then ask our attacker to construct the corresponding square root. In case 1 we get a random square root which gives us a pair of congruent squares and we have a chance to factor per the usual method. In case 2 we can compute a value for $\sqrt{-1}$ and future instances of case 2 will give us another instance of $\sqrt{-1}$ and a pair of congruent squares. Likewise case 3 and 4 give us values for $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{-2}$ and further instances again give us congruent squares. This with an expected $O(1)$ calls to the $\sqrt{u}$ extractor we will factor $n$.
3. The zero-knowledge nature of the signature oracle does provide assurance that the factoring problem is equivalent.

Comment: To be honest, I don't get how your "zero knowledge" argument proves that we can turn an algorithm that breaks EUF-CMA (thus with the help of a signature oracle), into an algorithm that can factor $n$ _without the help of said signature oracle_, as positively needed. I was [update: wrongly, I'm told] expecting a proof that requires rewinding the algorithm, the forking lemma, or something on that tune... that I fail to grasp! I should perhaps ask a simpler question on guiding me thru the proof of RSA FDH by Coron. Update: did [that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89847/555).

Answer (score 0):

This answers my own Q1 and Q3. Q2 still flies above my head, but getting closer.

Q1 asked an argument why it can't help factoring $n$ that by examining Rabin-Williams signatures for known or chosen messages $M$, an adversary can find loads of pseudo-random $m=16\,H_k(M)+12$ with known $\left(\frac m p\right)$ and $\left(\frac m q\right)$; when for a given $m$, there is no known way to find these two quantities (only their product).

An argument is that adversaries have efficient alternate ways, requiring no signature or queries to a signature oracle, to find pseudo-random $m$ with whatever combination of non-zero $\left(\frac m p\right)$ and $\left(\frac m q\right)$ they see fit (see below). Thus having the same ability using signatures (or a signature oracle using a random oracle to prepare $m$) can't be of sizable usefulness in factoring.

Start from a random $x\in[1,n)$. Unless $\gcd(n,x)$ was a factor of $n$
$$\begin{array}{llclcl}
m_0&\gets x^2\bmod n&\text{verifies}&\left(\frac{m_0}p\right)=+1&\text{and}&\left(\frac{m_0}q\right)=+1\\
m_1&\gets n-m_0&\text{verifies}&\left(\frac{m_1}p\right)=-1&\text{and}&\left(\frac{m_1}q\right)=-1\\
m_2&\gets2\,m_0\bmod n&\text{verifies}&\left(\frac{m_2}p\right)=-1&\text{and}&\left(\frac{m_2}q\right)=+1\\
m_3&\gets-2\,m_0\bmod n&\text{verifies}&\left(\frac{m_3}p\right)=+1&\text{and}&\left(\frac{m_3}q\right)=-1\\
\end{array}$$

Having one such $m_i$ of the appropriate kind, it's easy to make more: just multiply by a square and reduce modulo $n$. After pre-computation of a few squares, we can produce nearly one new $m\equiv12\pmod{16}$ per modular multiplication, by choosing which square we use this time according to a few high-order bits of the previous $m$.

---

Q3 asked why we consider arguments on the tune of *if we could exhibit existential signature forgeries with access to a signature oracle, then we could factor it's $n$* as a good reason to trust a signature system.

I was making a rather basic confusion between

1. if adversaries with access to a signature oracle could exhibit existential signature forgeries, they could also factor $n$ (and make a total break)
2. if adversaries with access to a signature oracle could exhibit existential signature forgeries, they could also factor $n$ *without access to the signature oracle* (and make a total break with only the public key).

1 states [break (s)EUF-CMA for $n$ ] ⟹ [factor $n$ given $n$ and signatures under $n$ aplenty]. 2 states [break EUF-CMA for $n$ ] ⟹ [factor $n$ given $n$ ]. Thus 2 is a strictly better guarantee.

The difference is subtle. I was pointed literature that (rightly) states that 1 holds but is not reassuring, and does not point that 2 holds and is reassuring. That was my mistake when I asked Q3.

A proof of 2 (that, I'm convinced, holds for $H_k$ per FDH) is an excellent reason (beyond faster public-key operations) to use Rabin rather than RSA, *if* we disregard the potential for side channels, for [implementation errors](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/368.pdf) due to the added complexity, and for total break due to improper choice of $H_k$. The later issue has occurred for ISO/IEC 9796(-1):1991 where [an attack](http://fragrieu.free.fr/paper9796.pdf#page=7) causes a total break from the signature of 4 chosen messages, and ISO/IEC 9796-2:1997 where [another](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/203.pdf#page=15) does so for feasibly many messages and hashes of practical size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment (regarding Q3). Isn't 1. saying: break EUF-CMA $\implies$ factor $n$ (hence, by contrapositive: factor $n$ is hard $\implies$ EUF-CMA secure)? While 2 is saying EUF-KeyOnly $\implies$ factor $n$ (which by contrapositive only gives EUF-KeyOnly security).

So isn't 1 a strictly *better* guarantee? I must have misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @hakoja: I've expanded the answer.