# Are digital signatures unique for the messages they sign?

Tags: public-key, signature, dsa

Practical implementations of digital signature algorithms (DSAs) employ hash functions to ensure that input is small and of a fixed sized; otherwise, DSAs would be too slow for most real-world applications. Given that hash functions map arbitrarily long inputs to (smaller) fixed sized outputs, you may have several inputs map to the same output. Thus, when used with DSAs, you may have two (or more) inputs that get verified by the same signature because the inputs map to the same hash value.

**My question is:** if we did not use a hash function, or if we could assume that there exist no collisions in the hash function, are the signatures generated by a DSA guaranteed to be unique? Or, like hash functions, is it possible to have multiple signatures validate the same input?

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/91492/102990) talks about how ECDSA does not provide "strong existential unforgeability" because "if (,) is a valid signature for some message, then the different (,−) also is valid for the same message." To me, it sounds like this that signatures are not unique (at least under ECDSA).

Answer (score 5):

> if we could assume that there exist no collisions in the hash function ... is it possible to have multiple signatures validate the same input?

That depends on the signature algorithm.

In some cases, for example, RSA with PKCS v1.5 SSA padding, that is impossible; from the signature, you can recover the hash (and hence a single signature cannot be valid to two different hashes).

In other cases, for example, ECDSA, it can happen; for a prime order curve (e.g. Sec256r1) a validly generated signature (that is, one for which $r$ is an $x$ coordinate to a point on the curve) will be valid for at least two different hashes.

Answer (score 2):

> If we did not use a hash function, or if we could assume that there exist no collisions in the hash function, are the signatures generated by a (generic digital signature scheme) guaranteed to be unique?

In general no, there is not a single signature for a given message (or hash) for a general definition of digital signature. Many signature schemes are *randomized*, including [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) and [DSA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=24): signing the same message twice will (most often) generate different signatures.

> (..) ECDSA does not provide "strong existential unforgeability" because "if $(r,s)$ is a valid signature for some message, then the different $(r,n-s)$ also is valid for the same message." To me, it sounds like this that signatures are not unique (at least under ECDSA).

Yes this implies the signature is not unique, but it tells something more: that it's possible to turn a signature into a different signature valid for the same message (and hash), without knowledge of the private key. It should be distinguished two criteria:

1. *Deterministic* signature (versus not): deterministic means the legitimate signer always generates the same signature. Randomized implies not deterministic (and strictly speaking means that even knowledge of the private key and history of the signatures made does not allow to predict the next signature).
2. *Strong* qualifier to existential unforgeability (versus mere existential unforgeability): that tells it's impossible to exhibit a *(message, signature)* pair that verifies and where *signature* is not the signature produced by the signer for this *message*. Compare to mere existential unforgeability, that tells it's impossible to exhibit a *(message, signature)* pair that verifies and where the signer did not sign this *message*.

Some signature schemes are such that a single signature can verify for a given message and hash, which (assuming existential unforgeability) implies 1 and 2. Example: strict implementation of [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22:90,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,721,null%5D).

For other signature schemes (that is such that the holder of the private key is able to produce different signatures for the same message and hash), the four combinations resulting from the criteria 1/2 above are possible, with at least the first three common:

- Deterministic signature with strong existential unforgeability: [EdDSA](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/)
- Randomized (thus non-deterministic) signature with strong existential unforgeability: [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22:78,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,314,null%5D), [DSA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=24).
- Randomized (thus non-deterministic) signature with mere existential unforgeability: [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1).
- Deterministic signature with mere existential unforgeability: [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) modified by using a CSPRNG keyed with a hash of the message and the private key, instead of a true RNG.