# Is it possible to cryptographically sign a message with a private key while keeping the pre-image content public?

Tags: encryption, signature, forgery

Essentially, I am looking for a way for user A to create a signed message that user B can 1) verify user A wrote (ie using ecrecover) and 2) the content of the message can be read by user B without needing user A’s private key.

I know it is possible for user A to use asymmetric encryption to sign a message that can be verified to be authentic, but I want user B to be able to read the content of that message and be able to rely on it without having to ask user A for a separate unencoded version of the message since user A could lie in the unencoded version.

Comment: The whole point of a signature is that the signer cannot lie about which message is being signed.

Comment: I don't see anything in what's asked that a standard signature does not do. In particular, "the content of the message can be read by user B without needing user A’s private key" is a standard feature of any signature scheme. The receiver does not need the signer's private key; they need the _public_ key. And "use asymmetric encryption to sign a message" has a terminology error: encryption encrypts, it does not sign. Perhaps you mean "use asymmetric _cryptography_ to sign a message".

Answer (score 3):

The security of the signature schemes doesn't require the message to be encrypted. The hash algorithm and the signature algorithm parameters are publicly known and the only secret **the signer's key must be kept secret all the time**. The hashing before signing is part of the signature scheme since the first true signature scheme; [Rabin Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_signature_algorithm) scheme.

In signature schemes security we have an adversary, forger, whose aim is forging a signature of a message that is never signed before. For a simple game, you can consider that the forger obtained $n$ pairs of $(\sigma_i,m_i)$ those are the message and its signature pair. Now, if the forger can output a new message $m \neq m_i$ for $i \in \{1,n\}$ with a valid signature $(\sigma,m)$ we call this a forgery for the digital signature with [Existantial Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature_forgery#Existential_forgery).

> Is it possible to cryptographically sign a message with a private key while keeping the pre-image content public?

Yes. As long as the message doesn't require to be confidential, there is no problem with the secure signature schemes like RSASSA-PSS, DSA, ECDSA, EdDSA, Schnoor, etc. The message can be signed unencrypted. This is common in digital media. You can see the content and the signature of a PDF, image, government documents, etc. and verify the signature if you have the true public key of the signer.

Keep in mind that, if the hash algorithm is not second pre-image resistant, then forgery is imminent. Use Collision resistant Cryptographic function to achieve at least [Universal Forgery (UF) under Chosen-Message Attack (CMA) UF-CMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/18298), like SHA2, SHAKE of SHA3, and BLAKE2.

If one only relies on the second pre-image resistance of the SHA-1 then, there are attacks on the collision of $\operatorname{SHA-1}$ like;

- Alice creates two messages that have the same SHA-1 value, $m_1$ is what Bob wants to sign and $m_2$ is what Alice has the advantage for their own.
- Alice sends $m_1$ to Bob and Bob reads and signs. $$(\sigma,m_1) = Sign( \operatorname{SHA-1}(m_1))$$
- Alice sends $(\sigma,m_2)$ to Charlie.
- Charlie verify the sign since $\operatorname{SHA-1}(m_1) = \operatorname{SHA-1}(m_2)$
- Alice benefits.

Do not set security on broken schemes even if they mitigate the current risks.

Comment: I do not understand this sentence: *Hopefully, none of the cryptographic hash algorithms ... are secure on their second pre-image resistance.*

Comment: @mafu I need to re-write that part. If one uses the collision resistance broken hash function, there is an attack. So always use collision-resistant hash functions.