# Quantitative security of signature scheme obtained by Fiat-Shamir tranform

Tags: signature, provable-security, fiat-shamir

I'm looking for a quantitative yet simple proof of the [EUF-CMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/555) security of a signature scheme obtained by Fiat-Shamir transform.

Recall the Fiat-Shamir transform starts from a 3-pass identification protocol with messages $(I,r,s)$, where $I$ is the prover's commitment, challenge $r$ is chosen uniformly at random in set $\Omega$ by the verifier, $s$ is the proof. It uses a hash $H$ into $\Omega$.

Generation of key pair $(\mathrm{pk},\mathrm{sk})$ in the signature scheme is as in the identification protocol. To sign message $M$, prover generates $I$ as in the identification protocol, computes $r:=H(I,M)$, then $s$ as in the identification protocol, then signature¹ $\sigma:=(I,s)$. The verification algorithm computes $r:=H(I,M)$ then applies the same verification procedure as the identification protocol, that is check $\mathcal V(\mathrm{pk},r,s)=I$.

By *quantitative*, I mean we assume an adversary can break the signature scheme with probability at least $\epsilon$ with time/effort $t$, $Q_S$ queries to the signature oracle, $Q_H$ queries to the hash oracle, and obtain some upper bound on the probability than an adversary can break the identification scheme with some time/effort.

I'm fine with a bound that's within a constant factor from optimal; requiring whatever plausible property on the 3-pass identification scheme, such as $I$ being uniformly random in some large enough set; $H$ being modeled as a random oracle; whatever algorithm being random polynomial time or even made deterministic (including using a PRG seeded with $\mathrm{sk}$ and $M$ for the random tape of the algorithm generating $I$, thus making the signature deterministic).

I know a standard reference is David Pointcheval and Jacques Stern's [Security Arguments for Digital Signatures and Blind Signatures](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2000_joc.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/s001450010003), but I'd like something simpler and more focused.

---

¹ The signature can also be $\sigma:=(r,s)$ or $\sigma:=(I,r,s)$, and there's a comparatively simple, tight security reduction between the three.

Comment: What about Theorem 19.7 (Page 733) in the textbook by [Boneh and Shoup](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf#page=736)?

Comment: @ckamath: Yes, [that theorem 19.7](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf#page=736) is closely related. Mainly, it's proof is more complex than I dream of and manage to fully follow so far. I vaguely hope for a simpler proof even if that's at the cost of a somewhat less tight bound, or as a trampoline. Also, and importantly, this theorem is stated for the Schnorr identification protocol and signature, and I don't follow the proof well enough to decide if it uses the rather special properties of that identification protocol.

Comment: [Theorem 19.14](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf#page=755) generalises Theorem 19.7 to Sigma protocols. I suppose you are looking for a simpler proof of this?

Comment: @ckamath: [Theorem 19.14](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf#page=755) tells we can built a secure ID protocol from a sigma protocol. I'm rather after a proof of [Theorem 19.16](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf#page=757), one simple enough that I manage to fully understand it.