# Can a private key be reverse engineered when a 3rd party has a lot of my digital signatures?

Tags: public-key, signature

I am wondering how secure it is to share digital signatures with a 3rd party (signed using one private key).

For example, let's say I'm signing a million different messages with my private key and send to a 3rd party. How likely is it that this 3rd party can reverse-engineer my private key simply because they have a million signatures?

Basically, is it safe to implement a system where every message is signed by the user's private key?

Comment: @Maeher thanks! so in my case the messages I'm signing are NOT controlled by the 3rd party at all, so this would be safe if I understand this correctly. Right?

Comment: Per my (accepted) [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/100956/555): for a signature system that's secure under EF-CMA (as most modern signature systems like ECDSA, EdDSA, DSA, RSASSA-PSS... are believed to be), then you are safe; and you would still be safe even if adversaries could control the messages signed, and be content with obtaining any signature for any new message.