# Security of this MAC scheme

Tags: hash, symmetric, collision-resistance, mac

I'm studying for a cryptography exam, I have this question from a past exam:

Consider the MAC with key $k$, based on a block cipher $E_{(k)}$ with block size $n$, and a collision-resistant hash function $h$ with output size $n$.
The MAC on a message m is calculated as:
$$ \text{MAC}(m) = E_{h(m)}(k) $$

- Discuss the security of this MAC scheme.

Obviously, the security of this scheme depends on the hash function chosen, the block cipher, and the length of $n$.

What other considerations can be made?

Answer (score 1):

Given a MAC scheme as $\text{MAC}(k,m) = E_{h(m)}(k)$

- take the message $m$ and hash it, these are public knowledge for the [security game of MACs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/18298)
- Now use the decryption of the Encryption function, what do you get?