# Signature forgery in different adversarial settings

Tags: signature, terminology, adversarial-model

I'm currently studying the different adversarial settings for digital signatures.

In Goldwasser, Micali and Rivests [paper](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs276/fa20/notes/Goldwasser-Micali-Rivest.pdf#page=4) they propose three different chosen message attack settings, which are vastly different.
More specifically they specify:

- Generic chosen message attacks
- Directed chosen message attacks
- Adaptive chosen message attacks

Why is it that all of these are just categorized as chosen message attacks in most literature?

For example EUF-CMA; it is just implicitly understood that this refers existential unforgeability under adaptively chosen message attacks?

Furthermore, does there exists a commonly known abbreviation which specify which chosen message attack I'm talking about? Something like gCMA, dCMA and aCMA?

Comment: The link is broken, but I guess it's meant [this](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs276/fa20/notes/Goldwasser-Micali-Rivest.pdf#page=4). A [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/555), which answer tells that yes, EUF-CMA came to be understood as secure under adaptive chosen message attacks. Question could be tagged [tag:terminology].

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That's the correct paper, I've changed the link to direct to the one you found and added "terminology" to the tags.

I found the same thread as you referenced, and it explains the different security models in great detail, however it says nothing about the different kinds of CMA.