# What is the advantage of a probabilistic PKC over a traditional PKC?

Tags: encryption, public-key, probabilistic-encryption

While reading through a textbook, I came across the idea of a probabilistic public key cryptosystem, which uses a probabilistic TM to generate the public encryption and private decryption algorithm; it is possible the encryption algorithm is probabilistic. If the encryption algorithm were not probabilistic, would the PPKC have an advantage of a traditional, non-probabilistic PKC? Can a traditional PKC offer a probabilistic encryption algorithm?

Comment: A non-probabilistic key generation algorithm always outputs the very same key because key generation algorithms don't take inputs.

Comment: @SEJPM so the advantage of PPKC is that the encryption algorithm can produce different results for the same input, reducing the possibility the encryption of identical messages is repeated?

Comment: Note that the term 'public key cryptosystem' includes signature algorithms; you can have both secure deterministic signature algorithms and secure randomized ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every secure public key cryptosystem *must* have a probabilistic encryption algorithm.**

Suppose this was not the case and consider [the usual IND-CPA game](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26738/23623).
An attacker can now win this game with probability 1 as follows:

1. He chooses two distinct messages $m_1,m_2$ at his liking and submits them to the challenger.
2. The challenger chooses a bit $b\in\{0,1\}$ uniformly at random and answers with $c'=c_b=E_{pk}(m_b)$.
3. The adversary computes $c_0=E_{pk}(m_0)$, if $c_0=c'$ he outputs 0, otherwise 1.
4. As the encryption algorithm is non-probabilistic, ie deterministic his choice for $b$ is right 100% of the time because he can be sure to always to the same value as the challenger.