# Use of OAEP in RSA Encryption

Tags: rsa, oaep

I am working on creating an RSA Algorithm and learned that OAEP is a padding scheme that is commonly used before encrypting using RSA. Is this step necessary? Will it harm the integrity/security of the encrypted text?

Comment: I once heard a wise man say that RSA padding should really be called "armoring" instead of "padding", because it's totally insecure without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this step necessary?

**Yes**. Assuming you don't want to adopt a RSA-KEM based approach, you need some form of padding to gain full [IND-CCA2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26738/23623) security (textbook RSA even lacks the much weaker IND-CPA security!) and OAEP is the preferred such scheme, having [a security reduction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2000/061) for IND-CCA2 (that is, it's IND-CCA2 as long as some reasonable assumptions hold).