# When do I need to use hybrid cryptography?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, elliptic-curves, hybrid-encryption

I need to provide confidentiality for a protocol. The protocol message size is between 100 bytes to 500 bytes. Do I need to use asymmetric encryption or hybrid cryptography?

Comment: 500 bytes is too large for RSA-OAEP with RSA-4096, you'd have to use an RSA key of about 5000 bits length, but this may be too slow for you.

Comment: What about Curve25519?

Comment: Or do I need to use hybrid cryptography

Comment: Are you sending more than one of these messages between the same pair of participants? Because if so, using hybrid crypto might still be more efficient even if you could encrypt each individual message directly with a public-key scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The protocol message size is between 100 bytes to 500 bytes. Do I need
>   to use asymmetric encryption or hybrid cryptography?

To support 500 byte messages, you need about your (direct) encryption scheme to work on about 5000 bits (e.g. for [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), [Paillier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem), [ElGamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption)) to provide room for the padding to gain [CCA2 security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26738/23623). At 5000 bits, these schemes become somewhat slow, so you should definitely make a measurement in either case between a hybrid and a direct solution (using e.g. RSA-5000 with [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) and maybe the exponents 3, 17 and 65537).

> What about Curve25519?

*If* you could reversible encode your message onto an elliptic curve point (not easy), you could use ElGamal or [Cramer-Shoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%E2%80%93Shoup_cryptosystem) on Curve25519 to encrypt messages of up to 32 bytes. Of course 32 bytes is much less than you want to encrypt so direct encryption is out.

Normally with Curve25519 and the other schemes you will do hybrid encryption, either as [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or directly by encrypting a symmetric key (using a CCA2 secure or specialized scheme like RSA-KEM) and AE encrypting the message. As an additional bonus you can then potentially re-use this shared key for multiple messages if you can do the neccessary nonce / IV management, i.e. you can guarantee that you can come up with a unique nonce for each message.