# Bit Flipping Attack on CBC Mode

Tags: encryption, cbc, modes-of-operation

To perform a bit flipping attack, the previous block is modified by using XOR. This results in an altered plaintext. However, now the ciphertext of the previous block is altered, hence it will result in an invalid format. Am I correct or am I missing something?

For example, suppose I have the following plaintext `name=jcconvenant;photo=picture.jpg;admin=false;colour=red;`

and the correspoding ciphertext `c26a5697689463d662f540e55e2a1ecef9c5df20133dfe49d6d3c369679a95ff4f4c5a490f530b2a2f25db40da64f1e9302724ce61b9a435e23f4d600252a143`

Suppose we perform a bit flipping attack and get the following ciphertext
`c26a5697689463d662f540e55e2a1ecef9c5df20133dfe49d6c1d07071c495ff4f4c5a490f530b2a2f25db40da64f1e9302724ce61b9a435e23f4d600252a143`

Then the resulting plaintext will still look corrupted.

`¶ä╚°  h8ì│►Nƒz│Ioé¤ßkü2KÀQiý4I@pg;admin=true;;colour=red;`

Is there a way to perform bit flipping while still obtaining a valid plaintext?

Comment: So one block will always be garbage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Bit Flipping attack

Decryption process in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is performed as
\begin{align}
P_1 =& Dec_k(C_1) \oplus IV\\
P_i =& Dec_k(C_i) \oplus C_{i-1},\;\; 1 < i \leq nb,
\end{align}
where $nb$ is the number of blocks.

If you know the position of the target byte, then you can modify the corresponding ciphertext position in the previous ciphertext block. For example; if you modify a byte in the ciphertext $C_{i-1}$, then $P_i$ will be changed by one block since $C_{i-1}$ only affects the plaintext $P_i$ by $\oplus$. We can see visually in the below figure;

[image: Figure for both case]

$\color{red}{\textbf{Red case:}}$ A ciphertext byte of $C_2$ modified. This affects the corresponding byte in the next plaintext block $P_3$ and the corresponding full plaintext block $P_2$ which has the same index as the modified ciphertext which is garbage. This can be seen as there is an error.

**$\color{ForestGreen}{\textbf{Green case:}}$** an $\text{IV}$ byte is modified (green), this affects only the corresponding byte in the first plaintext $P_1$. If the target plaintext is in the first block, this will not leave a trace.

### An example

Consider this simple message

`msg = "Buy 1000 lots of waffles"`

Now the attacker intercepts the message and now the default structure and want to modify it into

`msg = "Buy 5000 lots of waffles"`

Here is the sample Python code ( [the full code is here](https://github.com/kelalaka153/CBC-Bit-Flipping-Attack) );

```
def bitFlip( pos, bit, data):
    raw = b64decode(data)

    list1 = list(raw)
    list1[pos] = chr(ord(list1[pos])^bit)
    raw = ''.join(list1)
    return b64encode(raw)
```

With a call `ctx = bitFlip(4,4,ctx)` changes the 1 into 5.

This is the green case attack, that leaves no garbage block. Some file formats, like PDF, can live with the red case attack.

### A Little Theory

[CBC](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4074066A/en) mode for encryption can only provide [Ind-CPA security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87033/18298). CPA security doesn't resist active attacks, like CCA (See this post [Ind- notions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298) for details). Therefore an active attacker can modify the pure CBC ciphertext on their behalf. If the message format is known, this can cause devastating effects especially if the important part is in the first block.

### The Mitigation

The attack is possible since there is no integrity and authentication on the data. A [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) or an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) can be used to prevent this like AES-CBC-HMAC if the CBC mode is a must to use.

In other cases, it is better to use modern encryption schemes. The [authenticated encryption with Associated Data (AEAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which provides confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity. The examples are AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305. In TLS 1.3., [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode),[GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), and [poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) are standardized authenticated encryption modes.

There are alternatives to the above like AES-GCM-SIV which is designed to resist the (nonce,key) pair resue problem of the CTR based encryptions ( all of TLS 1.3 has) and xChaha20-Poly1305 that uses 192-bit nonces to reduce the chance of collision into very low probability.

Comment: I think the note is more like the conclusion. If you want a different note: you can do a single bit flip in the first block by altering the IV. Tricky isn't it, to not answer these kind of questions here ;)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the green case :) Created an image and changed the answer around that.

Comment: @kelalaka I may be missing something, but does this mean the question "Is there a way to perform bit flipping while still obtaining a valid plaintext?" has a negative answer?

Comment: @FelipeJacob one should define the valid plaintext. If you are talking about a real language, I would like to note that plaintexts are not limited to this. For example, it can be a GPS position or any binary value. In any case of the attack, you change one bit so that you expect that it works, one may have a change to execute as padding oracle attack if the other side sending an error. But if you have pre-knowledge about the structure of the plaintext, than the attack can be very devastating.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you modifying the ciphertext or the IV? Can you explain more the "bit" argument of the bitFlip function?

Comment: @OneCuriousPerson well, the attacker has the IV and the ciphertexts. Depending on the  position they can modify the IV or ciphertexts. In the The Yellow case (IV), one can change 1 to 0 or vs. that is flipping the bit. In this case, it can effect only on bit of ciphertexts. In the ciphertexts case, bit flipping effects two plaintext blocks; one has only one bit flipped and the other becomes a garbage. Hope this is clear for you.