# 64 bit clock cipher with CFB mode. One-byte defected from ciphertext. What is the number of bits defected from plaintext

Tags: modes-of-operation, cfb

I have a question from an exam;

We encrypted a message of size 100 Bytes with CFB. In the transmission, byte number 12 got defected. How many bits defected will be in the decryption. The answer is 72 bits and I don't understand why?

Comment: yes the block has 64 bit size.but i still don't understand...

Comment: Hint: CFB encryption and decryption are pictured [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)). Redraw it in your case (which uses a different block width). Examine what "transmitted byte number 12 got defected" means in this, and what that change _can_ influence in the decryption. Notice that, contrary to what the question states, we can _not_ tell for sure how many bits _are_ influenced, and that 72 bits actually is extremely unlikely. The actual answer is 2 to 72 bits.

Comment: Is "defected" errored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decryption of CFB mode as follows;

$$ P_i = E_k(C_{i-1}) \oplus C_i$$
$$C_0= \operatorname{IV}$$

**Bit flipping attack in CFB**

If there is a Bit Flipping attack in the ciphertext then we have two cases.

[image]

$\color{red}{\textbf{Red case:}}$ The last ciphertext bit is flipped. This only affects the corresponding plaintext block. So the attacker can change a plaintext bit without affecting any other bits.

**$\color{ForestGreen}{\textbf{Green case:}}$** Assuming that the $i$th ciphertext bit is changed, $ 0 \leq i < n$ where $n$ is the total number of blocks, then this time two plaintexts blocks are affected. We can also see from the equations, too;

$$ P_i = E_k(C_{i-1}) \oplus \color{blue}{C_i}$$
$$ P_{i+1} = E_k(\color{blue}{C_{i}}) \oplus C_{i+1}$$

Note: Bit flipping on IV of CFB mode has no good effect as in [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66086/18298) mode.

**Your question**

Since you have 100 Bytes, and 64-bit block cipher has 8-byte block size, the 12th-byte number falls into the second ciphertext. If it falls into the last one then only one byte is effected, $\color{red}{\textbf{red case}}$.

Now, since we are in the **$\color{ForestGreen}{\textbf{green case}}$**, for a defected one-byte $C_i$, we will see two plaintexts are effected $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$. $P_i$ has one byte defection and $P_{i+1}$ has full block defection.

**Fgrieu** gave the probabilities of the defection in the comments. As noted, the defection is not clear about how many bits are flipped. It may be 1 or 8. Also, the affected full block is not under control. For example, if we assume that the cipher has avalanche criteria we expect each of the ciphertext bits has 50% probability to have a flip. Therefore we can say it is between 1 and 64. So the total number of affected bits is between 2 to 72.

**Let finish this with mitigations:**

The attack/defection is possible since there is no integrity on the data. A [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) or an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) can be used to prevent, or better use [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which provides confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity. In TLS 1.3., [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) and [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) are standardized authenticated encryption modes.

Comment: i'm sure if the answer in the exam(72 ) is wrong or i still dont get it.as i see it every block after number 12 will be defected but there is only 100 byes .each block size is 64 bits which is 8 bytes hence, 12 block approximately. so if there is only 12 and the last one got defected ..i mean i get it wrong.can you explain the calculation ?

Comment: For a 64-bit block cipher there will be 2 to 72 bits in error, rather than 72 bits as the question's account of the problem/solution states. 2 could occur for a 1-bit error in $C_i$ combined with the unlikely case that it causes only a 1-bit error in $E_k(C_i)$; which for an ideal cipher occurs with probability $64/(2^{64}-1)$. 72 could occur for an 8-bit error in $C_i$ combined with the unlikely case that it causes a 64-bit error in $E_k(C_i)$; which for an ideal cipher occurs with probability $1/(2^{64}-1)$.