# AES-CBC decrypts to wrong output?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, cbc

Someone I know showed this to me, and I can't put a finger to why it's happening. Am I missing something?

They encrypt the text, and the output is really guessable. $u\to t$, $i\to h$ (it's one letter behind), the $?$ are just spaces.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me the name of the software that is shown above?

Comment: This is GCHQ's [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/).

Comment: For the sake of future references, could you write the encryption key completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They trick you with the IV. The IV must be the same for encryption and decryption so that the encryption has the functionality that is;

$$ m = D_k(IV,E_k(IV,m))$$
To surprise you, they modify the IV according to their desire but you failed to see that. This is the more general case of the [Bit-Flipping attack on the CBC mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66085/bit-flipping-attack-on-cbc-mode).

This attack works because the message has only one block and the change on the IV only modifies the first block. Nothing special there.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a key $K$. Pick a one-block message $m$ and the desired ciphertext $c$. Then compute the IV for CBC as follows:

$$c=E_K(IV\oplus m)\iff D_K(c)\oplus m=IV$$

where $E_K$ is AES encryption under the key $K$ and $D_K$ is the corresponding decryption and $\oplus$ is bitwise XOR.

Now you have the IV that maps $m$ to $c$ under the key $K$ with all three of them being freely choosable.