# Help with encryption question

Tags: encryption

I came across the following question and it is confusing me.

I'm completely new to cryptography, so please excuse the beginners question.

> "Having just completed a course in Cryptography, Tom and Jerry start a
>   new  business to manufacture and market cryptography products. Tom
>   designs an encryption algorithm $E_k(m)$ which produces a ciphertext upon
>   encrypting message m with a key k and keeps the algorithm a secret,
>   but the length of $E_k(m)$ is made public. Then Jerry enthusiastically
>   advises Tom to increase the security by  constructing $(E_k(m)\oplus m) \Vert (E_k(m)\oplus 1111…11)$ as the final ciphertext.
>
> Here $ \vert\vert $ is the concatenation symbol and $\oplus$ is the XOR operator.
>
> ***Is this a good scheme?***"

Initially at first glance I can see that the new algorithm is more secure, but I couldn't actually get any ciphertext from the equation. Does that make it secure? or does it make it useless because there isn't any ciphertext to decrypt? OR is there ciphertext and I have just tackled it the wrong way?

I am probably going to kick myself, I'm probably missing the entire point.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE! Some hints: Note that your new ciphertext is a concatenation of 2 parts. Both have same length. Three properties of $\oplus$: We can change the order of the strings we are xoring, what happens if you xor a string with itself? What happens if you xor a string with zero? This should help to show that the scheme is insecure

Comment: Ultimately there is an answer here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68708/58690 :)

Comment: Hi Daniel. Could you please create more specific title to your question next time you post? You can maybe imagine that "Help with encryption question" is not particularly *distinct* on a crypto Q/A site.