# How can CPA-secure LWE cryptosystem be broken by an active attacker?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

The LWE-cryptosystem is only CPA-secure as for example stated in [A Decade of Lattice-Based Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/939.pdf). Consider the following system described there (Section 5.2)

- The secret key is a uniform LWE secret $s \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$, and the public key is some $m \approx (n+1) \log(q)$ samples $(\bar{a}_i, b_i = \left <\bar{a}_i, s \right > +e$ collected as a the columns of a matrix $A$
  $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \bar{A} \\ b^t \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{(n+1) \times m}$$
  where $b^t = s^t \bar{A} +e e^t \mod q$.
- To encrypt a bit $\mu \in \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$ using the public key $A$, one chooses a unifrom $x \in {0,1}^m$ and outputs the ciphertext
  $$c = A \cdot x + (0, \mu \cdot \lfloor \frac{q}{2} \rceil) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n+1}$$
- To decrypt using the secret key $\mathbb{s}$, one computes:
  $$(-s, 1)^t \cdot c = (-s, 1)^t  \cdot A \cdot x +\mu \cdot \lfloor \frac{q}{2} \rceil) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n+1}$$
  $$ = e^t \cdot x + \mu \cdot \lfloor \frac{q}{2} \rceil) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n+1}$$
  $$\approx \mu \cdot \lfloor \frac{q}{2} \rceil \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n+1} \mod q$$
  and tests whether it is closer to $0$ or $\frac{q}{2} \mod q$.

The paper states that "we note that the system is trivially breakable under an active, or chosen-ciphertext, attack".

How would such an attack look like? I would consider to encrypt the $0$ bit with $x$ being the all $1$-s vector to retrieve $e$ and then retrieve $s$ via $\bar{A}^{-1} \cdot (b-e)$. Are there any other ways known? And are there known ways to extend these attacks to CPA-secure version of the NIST-pqc finalist candidates, for example, Kyber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that adversary $A$ chooses two messages $m_1 = 0$ and $m_2 = 1$ as per [Ind-CCA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298) game and plays against the challanger.

- Adversary A sends $m_1$ and $m_2$ to the challenger.
- Challenger randomly choose $b$ between $0$ and $1$; $b \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow}${0,1}
- Challenger calculates $c:=Enc(s,m_b)$ and send $c$ to $A$.
- Adversary performs additional operations in polynomial time, including calls to the encryption/decryption oracles, for ciphertexts different than $c$.

  - $c_0 = EncOracle(0)$
  - $c' = c \oplus c_0$

    i.e. execute a homomorphic addition of $m_b$ with zero!.
  - $m' = DecOracle(c')$

    This is a valid request since $c' \neq c$.
  - And we have $m' = m_b$
- if $m' = 0$ return $0$
  else return $1$

Adversary wins the game with an advantage 1.

In other words, the ciphertexts are malleable, there is no integrity to secure against CCA1 adversary.

Comment: Thanks! One question though: The attack laid out calls the decryption oracle _after_ obtaining the challenge. However, the description of IND-CCA1 linked mentions that the attacker has to call the decryption oracle _before_ obtaining the challenge:
"_That means: the adversary can encrypt or decrypt arbitrary messages before obtaining the challenge ciphertext._"
Would the attack laid out here not violate this requirement?