# Essential requirement for IND-CCA1 and IND-CCA2

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, indistinguishability

I am learning about the concept of two security notions called IND-, which include IND-CPA, IND-CCA1 and IND-CCA2. While I got some grasp understanding about the scenarios between the challenger & attacker for each of these models. I am still not able to comprehend what properties of a security model are required to "upgrade" from IND-CPA to IND-CCA1, thus IND-CCA2.

- Starting with IND-CPA, I understood that each encryption request must "result in randomly different outputs".
- What are the canonical descriptions for the next 2 transitions (IND-CPA -> IND-CCA1 and IND-CCA1 -> IND-CCA2)? I did some research and got some answers talking about "making the ciphertext tamperproof" ([LINK1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-IND-CPA-and-IND-CCA), [LINK2](https://people.csail.mit.edu/alinush/cse508-spring-2011/03-03-cpa-and-cca.pdf)) but still quite confused (e.g., they just mentioned CCA generally).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is our Canonical Q/A; [Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298) What is not clear there for you?

Comment: @kelalaka It really helped me understand the context of these notions. But I am still not able to find the condition to reach those type of security. For instance, this [LINK](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/why-ind-cpa-implies-randomized-encryption/) mentioned about what the encryption needs to improve to achieve IND-CPA, which is to randomize. I am still looking for stuff like that for IND-CCA1 and IND-CCA2.

Comment: Ind-CCAx requires a MAC to achive this. The CPA is malleable.

Comment: Example 1 [How can CPA-secure LWE cryptosystem be broken by an active attacker?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96591/18298) 2) [Bit Flipping Attack on CBC Mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66086/18298) 3) [Padding Oracles](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76713/18298) and many others due to lack of integrity or not using integrity correctly. You may search for _CPA attack_ for more and see the necessity of the integrity.

Comment: Thank you for your threads, I am checking them out