# The essential differences between IND-CCA1 and IND-CCA2?

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

For some encryption scheme $(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{D})$:

In the definition of IND-CCA, the adversary $\mathcal{A}$ can access the decryption oracle $\mathcal{D}$. The deep reason of this setting is to make sure that our scheme is able to "**protect the ciphertexts**"  (e.g. the integrity and authenticity).

So "protecting the ciphertexts" is what an IND-CPA secure scheme can not offer. And that's why IND-CCA is stronger than IND-CPA. Furthermore, IND-CCA2 allows $\mathcal{A}$ to make queries to $\mathcal{D}$ after $\mathcal{A}$ receives the challenge ciphertext $c^{*}$, which is so called "adaptive" query.

Then my question is:

- How should we **describe** this distinctive ability of resisting adaptive queries in IND-CCA2, in **a pellucid way** ?

In other words, "random bits-like ciphertexts" leads to IND-CPA security, "the protection of ciphertexts" leads to IND-CCA1 security. Then what leads to IND-CCA2 security?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/easy-explanation-of-ind-security-notions)

Comment: "protect the ciphertexts" is very imprecise, I don't think such a definition is enlightening at all.

Comment: Hi kelalaka and meshcollider ! I am aware of the definitions and security proofs of these models. So the content of that post is not very helpful to me. What I am looking for is **some words** to summarize the core differences between CCA1 and CCA2 in a short way just like "protect the ciphertexts "does (though it might not be that precise :-). Thus, this question is actually not an academic problem and doesn't have the standard answer.

Comment: The issue is that you're understanding of CCA1 security is already flawed. "protecting the ciphertexts" as you phrase it is neither sufficient nor necessary for CCA1 security.

Comment: CCA1 = Making decryption queries before seeing $c^*$ doesn't help you learn what's inside $c^*$; CCA2 = Making decryption queries before/after seeing $c^*$ doesn't help you learn what's inside $c^*$

Comment: In case of symmetric crypto, there are IND-CCA encryption schemes where all strings are valid ciphertexts: no decryption error.  I think the intuition 'protect the ciphertext' could be hard to be applied to this case.  https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2000/18800395/18800395.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IND-CCA1 is INDistinguishability under Chosen Ciphertext Attack.

IND-CCA2 is INDistinguishability under adaptive Chosen Ciphertext Attack.

In both, an adversary attempts to decipher a ciphertext $C$ by making queries to a decryption oracle that will decrypt anything. The difference is that in IND-CCA1, the queries are made without knowledge of $C$ (given to adversary after the queries), when in IND-CCA2 queries can be made with knowledge of $C$ (given to adversary early on, with prohibition to give $C$ to the decryption oracle).

IND-CCA1 models a decryption device *temporarily* made available to adversaries. IND-CCA2 makes that permanent.

Here are situations where IND-CCA2 encryption is desirable:

- There's a server that decrypts, then parses the deciphered plaintext as a (*message*, *signature*) pair and checks it against a public key (unrelated to the encryption/encryption key). If OK, the server acts according to *message*; otherwise it outputs "I won't do " *message*.
- Embassy A knows it's messages to B are intercepted by E and relayed (with the prefix INTERCEPT) encrypted to F; F deciphers then relays what starts with INTERCEPT to G, that A has penetrated. This puts A in an IND-CCA2 situation to attack the cipher from E to F (within the restriction that A can only submit messages starting with INTERCEPT).
- There's a server that decrypts, then remove padding, and a timing attack allows to know how much padding was removed.

Comment: Very inspiring! The words "temporarily" and "permanently" are exactly what I want. Thanks!