# Adversaries knowledge of the encryption algorithms internal workings in CPA

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

If I want to prove that an encryption algorithm is CPA secure (or that it isn't), then how much am I allowed to assume the attacker to know about the internal workings of the algorithm? Do I need to assume that the encryption algorithm is just a "black box" from the point of view of the attacker i.e. they can only query it for encryptions of different plaintexts but don't know anything about how it works? Or do I need to assume that the attacker knows everything about the internal workings except for possible secret values like keys?

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se] Do you know the [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle)? Did you read the basics of the  [Ind-CPA game](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298)? Attacker knows everything except the key..

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I need to assume that the attacker knows everything about the internal workings except for possible secret values like keys?

This one - that they have detailed knowledge of the algorithm (and the implementation if we are considering side channel attacks).

Assuming that they don't is known as "Security Through Obscurity"; that isn't greatly thought of...